# Retrieving polygon sides by a vertex array polygon

Tags: geometry

If given four 2d vertices, `(0, 0), (0, 2), (3, 0), (4, 5)`
How can I retrieve **all sides** of the polygon, like this?

```
((0, 0), (0, 2)) ((0, 0), (3, 0)), ((0, 2), (4, 5)), ((3, 0), (4, 5))
```

If I calculate all the line segments which can be made,
there will be some diagonal segments like `((0, 0), (4, 5)), ((0, 2), (3, 0))` that will cause error.

How can I retrieve only side segments of a general polygon?

Comment: Thought as an 2x2 array, 2 vertices are connected by a segment when only their row OR their column is equals; a diagonal connects point 0,0 to 1,1 (where numbers are the coordinates in the array).

Comment: @gengisdave so convert nonzero coords to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the vertices in an array:

```
           col1     col2
        -------------------
row1    | A(0,0) | B(0,2) |
        -------------------
row2    | C(3,0) | D(4,5) |
        -------------------
```

the vertices are connected by a segment (not a diagonal) when they belongs to the same row or column. eg. A and C are connected because the are in `col1`, the same with C and D (`row2`). B and C are not connected because they have different column and different row.

Comment: So i should convert vertices to two dimensional array. thanks!

Comment: There is absolutely no need in two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If point order is correct, then i-th edge of polygon connects i-th vertex with (i+1) one, and the last edge connects (N-1) vertex with 0-th vertex. Pseudocode:

```
for i = 0.. N - 2
   Edges[i][0] = Points[i];
   Edges[i][1] = Points[i + 1];
Edges[N-1][0] = Points[N-1];
Edges[N-1][1] = Points[0];
```

*(It is possible to join all operations inside the for cycle but loosing some clarity*)